# How to execute an HTTP Get with Params, RequestHeaders and RequestContent

Tags: flutter

I'm a couple of weeks into my Flutter journey. I have looked at a few tutorials on using a web service and returning data, but am unsure of a couple of things and how to apply to my web services.

I have completed my web app (written in Elevate Web Builder) and also my server side modules acting as my web services. Inside my web app I call the web service using a server request and the following parameters:

Params : Key and value pairs - used to pass authorization info
eg:

```
Params.Values['userid'] := 'test'
Params.Values['password'] := 'test-Password'
```

RequestHeaders - used to specify the content type
eg:

```
RequestHeaders.Values['Content-Type'] := 'text/plain'
```

RequestContent : Key and value pairs - used to send values to specify what to retrieve or what to save into the database
eg:

```
RequestContent.Values['webService'] := 'Get_StaffList'
RequestContent.Values['CompanyId'] := '123'
RequestContent.Values['OnlyActive'] := 'Y'
```

The Params are specified as URL parameters, but I'm not sure where I specify the RequestHeaders and RequestContent?

I have tried sending RequestHeaders and RequestContent as:

```
http.post('https://...', headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
           'webService': 'Get_StaffList',
           'CompanyId': '123',
           'OnlyActive': 'Y'
          });
```

but this didn't work. Any ideas how it should be sent in Flutter?

Thanks heaps,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought I'd let you know I got it working. I took what you suggested and looked at what the web service was receiving from the web app. Then modified the code in Flutter to send the data in the same format. This now works:

```
  final response = await http.post(
      Uri.encodeFull('http://mobileuser.pvapps.one:82/modules/rmo_daMLogin'),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
      body: 'rmoService=User_Login\n'
          'UserId=fred\n'
          'Password=abc123');
```

Thanks again for the help,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```dart
String server = "http://localhost:8008";

userSearch(String accessToken, String searchTerm) async {

  String url = server + "/_matrix/client/r0/user_directory/search";

  Map<String, String> headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "authorization": "Bearer $accessToken"};

  String body = jsonEncode({"search_term": searchTerm});

  Response response = await post(url, headers: headers, body: body);

  UserSearchObj users = UserSearchObj.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

  return users;
}
```

Comment: Hi Abuzer, thanks so much for the answer. Unfortunately this didn't work for me, but it's probably more to do with some incompatibility between Flutter's http and my web service. Appreciate the help.